# Why does this php function using foreach with an array not work?

Tags: php, fdf

I am trying to write the fieldname/value lines of an FDF file with the function below in PHP. The first "hey there" prints, but none of the others. I am just starting with PHP and would appreciate any help.

```
function writeFDFTextboxLines($reportNameToFieldNumsArray, $reportName, $fileHandle, $value) {
    echo "hey there <br />";
    $valuesArray = $reportNameToFieldNumsArray[$reportName];
    foreach($valuesArray as $fieldNums) {
        echo "hey there <br />";
        foreach($fieldNums as $fieldNum) {
            echo "hey there <br />";
            if(strlen($fieldNum) > 0) {
                echo "hey there <br />";
                fwrite($filehandle, '<< /T (' . $reportName . "Textbox" . $reportNameToFieldNumsArray[$reportName] . ') /V /(' . $value . ')>>' . "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A $reportNameToFieldNumsArray example is

```
$firstnameLastnameArray = array("report1" => array("1"), "report2" => array("1"), "report3" => array("1"), "report4" => array("1"), "report5" => array("1"), "report6" => array("1"), "report7" => array(), "report8" => array(), "report9" => array(), "report10" => array("1"), "report11" => array("1"), "report12" => array("1"), "report13" => array("1"), "report14" => array("1"), "report15" => array("1"), "report16" => array("6"), "report17" => array("1"),  "report18" => array("1"));
```

Comment: So `$valuesArray` is something like `array("1")`? Unclear how you think you can iterate over two levels within that.

Comment: None of the pdfs from the example have more than one field in them with the first name and last name. Most of the field numbers are "1" because most of these pdfs require the first name and last name to go in the first field. Some pdfs may require the same value to be entered in more than one field. Those pdfs will need more than one field number for the same value. Please take away your downvote if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$valuesArray` contains `array("1")`, so your first `foreach` loops around the array. But `$fieldNums` is not an array. Try to `var_dump($fieldNums)`, to see what it contains. It seem your don't need embeded foreach.

Comment: I really want to delete this question. I have been up too late.